# PropertyInfo.SetValue on a property List(Of Int32)

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.reflection

I Have a Class with some List Properties Like This:

```
Public Class ListPropertiesClass
    Public Property Id As List(Of Int32)
End Class
```

And another class where I use Reflection :

```
Public Class Test

   Public Sub MySub()

      Dim IdentityValue as Int32 = 100
      Dim PropertyName as String = "Id"
      Dim LPC as new ListPropertiesClass
      Dim pInfo As PropertyInfo

      pInfo = LPC.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName)
      If Not pInfo Is Nothing Then

          pInfo.SetValue(LPC, Convert.ToInt32(IdentityValue), Nothing)

       End If

   End Sub

End Class
```

But When I try to use it its not working because I'm trying to set a value of type Int32 to a List one, how can I Use the PropertyInfo.SetValue to Add List Itens ? And After adding how can I get the value also using reflection to get the value of the specific index of the list

```
pInfo.GetValue(LPC, Nothing)
```

I would be very happy if anyone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to first get the value of the current property (and check it) as below

this is for example as I don't remember the exact syntax of vb.net

```
Dim pValue = pInfo.GetValue(LPC, Nothing)
Dim castedValue As List(Of Integer) = TryCast(pValue, List(Of Integer))

If castedValue Is Nothing Then
   castedValue = New List(Of Integer)()
End If
castedValue.Add(IdentityValue)
pInfo.SetValue(LPC, Convert.ToInt32(IdentityValue), Nothing)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked almost on the first try. I Just have to change

pInfo.SetValue(LPC, Convert.ToInt32(IdentityValue), Nothing)

to 

pInfo.SetValue(LPC, castedValue, Nothing)

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, as you have pointed out already, you can't assign an `Int32` value to a `List(Of Int32)` property.
- Secondly, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly but I'll go along with it - Let's assign an instance of a **newly created** `List(Of Int32)` instance's reference to the property, using

Here goes nothing:

```
Dim newList As New List(Of Int32)
pInfo.SetValue(LPC, newList, Nothing)
```

Now, you can add stuff to the list (you already have a reference to it):

```
Dim newList As New List(Of Int32)
pInfo.SetValue(LPC, newList, Nothing)

newList.Add(10)
newList.Add(11);
```

It's not the property that stores the list.
The property stores a reference (a 4 byte = 32 bit long numerical value).
The reference, or pointer, or address is not the actual instance.

You use the reference to do things to the instance and you can have multiple references to the same instance.

**Change of perspective**

Suppose you were not interested in playing with Reflection the way I just did. Suppose you agree with the following modification:

```
Public Class ListPropertiesClass
    Public Property Id As List(Of Int32)

    Sub New()
        Property = New List(Of Int32)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Basically, you need an instance of `List(Of Int32)` for each instance of `ListPropertiesClass` and that's a trivial matter, so let's simply create the `List(Of Int32)` along with it's wrapper - No reflection here.

Now, suppose you want to use Reflection to add `Int32` values to that list.

First look at how you would accomplish that without Reflection:

```
LPC.Property.Add(10)     ' LINE 1
```

which can be translated into this equivalent code:

```
Dim theList As List(Of Int32)     ' LINE 2
theList = LPC.Property            ' LINE 3
theList.Add(10)                   ' LINE 4
```

If you're not entirely sure that the last 3 lines have precisely the same effect as the line commented with `' LINE 1` then I would suggest you brush up on classes, instances and references in general OOP.

Now, let's see what those last 3 lines are actually doing (without using Reflection - yet):

- `' LINE 2` is just a variable declaration
- `' LINE 3` is a **get** operation followed by an assignment
- `' LINE 4` is the invocation of a method

So, the key aspect here is that `' LINE 3` is a **get** not a **set**.

Now here's what you do:

Instead of declaring a variable which can store `List(Of Int32)` references we'll declare a variable which can store `Object`references

```
' so this line
' Dim theList as List(Of Int32)
' becomes this line
Dim theList As Object
```

Instead of "getting in a regular fashion" and assigning the value of the property to the variable we still do the assignment but we get the value using reflection

```
' so this line
' theList = LPC.Property
' becomes this line
theList = LPC.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(LPC, Nothing)
```

(notice the trailing `GetValue` call)

Instead of simply adding values to a list using a `List(Of Int32)` reference which points to a `List(Of Int32)` instance we will be invoking the `Add` method by using an `Object` reference which points to - you guessed it - a `List(Of Int32)` instance

```
' so this line
' theList.Add(10)
' becomes this line
theList.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(theList, New Object() { 10 })
```

Notice the [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method. Click on the link for a msdn article about it.

Wrapping it all up, it should look something like this:

```
Dim theList As Object
theList = LPC.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(LPC, Nothing)
theList.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(theList, New Object() { 10 })
```

Now you could settle for simply casting the `Object` reference to a `List(Of Int32)` reference and calling the `Add` method **without** reflection. In that case, the local variable can be `List(Of Int32)`:

```
Dim theList As List(Of Int32)
theList = TryCast(LPC.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(LPC, Nothing), List(Of Integer))
theList.Add(10)
```

Good luck!